# Android Studio: Session 'MainActivity': error, but there is no error

Tags: java, android-studio, runtime-error, android-gradle-plugin

Hi I have been racking my brain for hours, did research online but nobody seems to have an answer. My emulator was running my code no problem then I ran it again and I get "Session 'MainActivity': error". I looked through this main activity about 10 times but there is no error sign anywhere and it looks like it should be working fine, I mean it was working before no problem. So I'm not sure if there really is a problem I don't see that Android Studio is not pointing out properly or if this is a different problem all together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
package tekvision.codedecrypter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import gameInfo.GameDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //Runs before the application is created
    private Button mCampaignButton;
    private final Context context = this;

    //When the application is created
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Instantiate a GameDatabase object (this activity)
    final GameDatabase gDB = new GameDatabase(context);

    gDB.fillGameDatabase();

    //Keeps screen on so it doesn't fall asleep
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    //Finding button by button id after application is created
    mCampaignButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.campaignButtonID);

    //Checks if the campaign button is clicked
    mCampaignButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String ans =  gDB.getAnswer("Ancient",1);

            //Toast pop up message
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 ans ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            toast.show();


            //Intent to go from main activity to campaign Level Select Activity

            final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CampaignSelectLevel.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding and cleaning your project.
Build > Rebuild Project
and 
Build > Clean Project